# reduce/reduce conflict when parsing expressions without mixed operators

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc

The language in my compiler course assignment doesn't allow mixed operators in an expression without parentheses, presumably to not make us deal with implementing precedence. This means the following are valid expressions:

```
# Valid
1 + 2 + 3
1 + (2 * 3)
1
```

But this is not:

```
# Invalid
1 + 2 * 3
```

Neither is the empty expression. Excerpting from my actual grammar, the expression is parsed like this:

```
%token TNumber
%start expr

%%

expr : mulexpr
     | addexpr
     ;

mulexpr : mulexpr '*' term
        | term
        ;

addexpr : addexpr '+' term
        | term
        ;

term : '(' expr ')'
     | TNumber
     ;
```

However, this blows up with a reduce/reduce conflict. I'm *guessing* it's because a single-term expression like `123` can be reduced as `TNumber -> term -> mulexpr -> expr`, or `TNumber -> term -> addexpr -> expr`, but I'm not really sure. I'd prefer having the grammar unambiguous rather than hoping the ambiguity is what I think it is. However, I can't come up with a way to resolve this ambiguity.

My thinking is that I should add a rule `expr : term;`, and then somehow make `addexpr` and `mulexpr` require 2 or more terms, but I can't figure out how to express this.

**Update:** While I found a working solution, if there's one with less duplication of "code" it'll get the accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the recursion stop condition for `mulexpr` and `addexpr` be a two-term expression works:

```
expr : mulexpr
     | addexpr
     | term
     ;

mulexpr : mulexpr '*' term
        | term '*' term
        ;

addexpr : addexpr '+' term
        | term '+' term
        ;
```

<sub>(Figured this out five seconds after posting the question. SO makes for a great rubber duck.
I guess my brain just obsessively tried to avoid that sort of duplication.)</sub>